# Почему модальное окно всплывает только при нажатие на первую кнопку?

Tags: javascript

Модальное окно `product_congratulations` должно всплывать при нажатие на любую кнопку `product_button`, но оно всплывает только при нажатие на первую кнопку, не могу понять как устранить данную проблему.

[Полный код](https://codepen.io/DmitriyYaroshchuk/pen/vYzYmGO)

```js
if (event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
        const currentParentDIV = document.querySelector('.wrapper_product').closest('.product');
        console.log(currentParentDIV);
        currentParentDIV.classList.toggle('active');
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.querySelectorAll('.active').forEach((activeEl) => {
                activeEl.classList.remove('active')
            })
        },3000);
    }
```

Comment: В примере желательно предоставлять и `html` с которым имеешь дело. `document.querySelector('.wrapper_product')` выдаст только первый элемент с таким классом.

Comment: @ksa я предоставил полный код в задание

Comment: @ksa https://codepen.io/DmitriyYaroshchuk/pen/vYzYmGO

Comment: Я поклацал там по менюшке - "модалка" всегда открывалась разная. У каждого пункта - своя, судя по тексту.

Comment: @ksa странно у меня при нажатие на кнопку `купить` модалка не появляется. Появляется только в первом товаре то есть iPhone

Comment: Вона чего! До "Купить" я не доходил. :-\

Comment: @ksa там при нажатие на кнопку купить должна выпасть модалка `Спасибо за покупку...`, но она выпадает только у `iPhone`, а должна выпадать у каждого товара.

Comment: Я уже "дотыкал" до этого места. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> оно всплывает только при нажатие на первую кнопку, не могу понять как устранить данную проблему

Смотри, как я уже писал в комментариях.

```
const currentParentDIV = document.querySelector('.wrapper_product').closest('.product');
```

Находит самый первый элемент. А тебе нужно искать родителя относительно кнопки. Т.е. вот так

```
const currentParentDIV = event.target.closest('.product');
```

После такой правки у меня в твоем примере "Купить" стало работать у всех пунктов.

Comment: смотри я читал документацию по поводу метода `closeset` и в ней написано что данный метод возвращает родителя текущего элемента, то есть текущий элемент `button` а родитель его `wrapper_product`. Как же тогда он возвращает следующего родителя `product` ?

Comment: @NANO_996, не совсем так... `closeset` вернет родителя того элемента - к которому применили этот метод. А ты его применял не к тому элементу.